# Apply Complement to a list of matrices

Tags: logic

With a list of defined matrices

```
list={a,b,c,d}
```

How can I apply Complement to obtain

```
Complement[list,{b,c}]=={a,d}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess your main confusion is that when you do

```
RandomSeed[1234];
list = RandomReal[1, {4, 2, 2}]
Complement[list, list[[{2, 3}]]]
```

then the output of the matrices is in the wrong order. The documentation of `Complement` says

> The list returned by Complement is sorted into standard order.

An easy trick around this is to do the complement on the indices and not on the matrices itself. After that, you can use the indices to access the matrices in `list`:

```
list[[Complement[Range[Length[list]], {2, 3}]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also get the unsorted complement using `DeleteCases[list, Alternatives @@ {b, c}]]`.

```
RandomSeed[777];
list = RandomInteger[10, {5, 2, 2}];
MatrixForm /@ list // TeXForm
```

> $\left\{\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  10 & 1 \\
>  10 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  10 & 7 \\
>  6 & 6 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  8 & 2 \\
>  4 & 5 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 3 \\
>  8 & 8 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  9 & 3 \\
>  1 & 10 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\right\}$

```
comp = DeleteCases[list, Alternatives @@ list[[{2, 4}]]];
comp // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left\{\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  10 & 1 \\
>  10 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  8 & 2 \\
>  4 & 5 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  9 & 3 \\
>  1 & 10 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\right\}$

Answer (score 1):

Something I have done:

Use something like `Hold` to block how `Complement` searches arrays. In this case `MatrixForm` might make sense too.

For example:

```
Complement[Hold /@ list, Hold /@ {b, c}] ==  Hold /@ {a,d}
```