# How to apply the same unitary transformation to a list of square matrices?

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a unitary matrix U and a list of matrices Mlist how can I apply the unitary transformation to the list?

Comment: By mapping an appropriate function? Look up [‘Map’](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) as a start. You should also provide an example of these matrices and list. I notice that you asked a [question along the same lines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/165729/27951) before, regarding applying ‘Complement’ to a list of matrices. Perhaps some of the techniques shown in the answers there provide a starting point as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a sample example that uses `Map`. I have defined a function to generate any  $2\times2$ $SU(2)$ transformation upto an overall phase and used one such transformation to change the list of matrices.

```
matrices = RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, {10, 2, 2}];

unitary[θ_, ϕ1_, ϕ2_] := {
 {E^(I ϕ1) Cos[θ], E^(I ϕ2) Sin[θ]}, 
 {-E^(I ϕ2) Sin[θ], E^(- I ϕ1) Cos[θ]}
 };

(ConjugateTranspose[
      unitary[π/4, π/5, π/6]].#.unitary[π/4, π/ 5, π/6]) & /@ matrices;
```

Answer (score 5):

Matrix operations automatically use parallelization when possible, so using matrix operations and avoiding [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map) will provide a speed gain. Using @Henrik's example:

```
a = Map[ConjugateTranspose[U].#.U&, matrices]; //RepeatedTiming
b = cf[matrices,ConjugateTranspose[U],U]; //RepeatedTiming
c = Transpose[ConjugateTranspose[U] . Transpose[matrices] . U]; //RepeatedTiming

Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance=5}, a==b==c]
```

> {0.0086, Null}
>
> {0.0024, Null}
>
> {0.0016, Null}
>
> True

So, using [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) and [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose) is faster than @Henrik's compiled version.

Note that I used 10^4 matrices instead of 10^5. As the number of matrices increases, the compiled version eventually becomes faster.

Comment: Very interesting. Must be very machine dependend. On my old Haswell, method c takes 1.5 to 2 times as long as the compiled version. Might have to do with slower RAM (@1600 MHz)? This is why I got the habit to leave MTensors in their natural ordering.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I also get [similar slower results](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qFfEN.png) for `c` on a 2013 MacBook Pro

Answer (score 4):

If you have to do that really often and with numerical matrices, it may be worth the effort to write a `CompiledFunction` with `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}`. This is usually faster than using `Map`, since it can also utilize parallelization.

```
cf = Compile[{{A, _Complex, 2}, {U, _Complex, 2}, {V, _Complex, 2}},
   U.A.V,
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ];

n = 4;
matrices = RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, {100000, n, n}];
U = RandomVariate[CircularUnitaryMatrixDistribution[n]];

a = Map[ConjugateTranspose[U].#.U &, matrices]; // RepeatedTiming // First
b = cf[matrices, ConjugateTranspose[U], U]; // RepeatedTiming // First
Max[Abs[a - b]]
```

> 0.077
>
> 0.021
>
> 0.

Comment: I was totally unaware of the CircularUnitaryDistribution function.

Comment: Yeah, it's great, isn't it? I experienced all the matrix distributions for myself only recently.

Comment: Sure it is! Great to stumble upon such functions every once in a while.

Comment: @Subho95 The reason `Map` is so slow here is that the function defined in terms of `f` is uncompilable. The consequent unpacking of `matrices` also contributes to the slowness. `Map[ConjugateTranspose[U].#.U &, matrices]` is about 4-5 times faster and does not unpack `matrices`. The compiled `cf` and the difference with the compiled is another 4 times faster, which speedup is explained by parallelization (on my quad-core i7).

Comment: @Michael E2, Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good point. I edited the post.